# Adding sub-arrays based on the label in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a bit of an issue figuring this out.

I have an array object per customer, per year of the month:

```
[
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 57.62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 1"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 234.65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 2"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192"
    data: [0, 0, 490.43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    label: "Client 3"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192"
    data: [0, 0, 0, 94.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    label: "Client 1"
  }
]
```

How do I add the two objects with the same label (Client 1) and create a new array that would look like this?

```
[
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 57.62, 94.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 1"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 234.65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 2"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192"
    data: [0, 0, 490.43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    label: "Client 3"
  },
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any attempts made to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the values for each label and sum the `data` array for objects with the same same label.

```js
let arr=[{color:"#009192",data:[0,0,57.62,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],label:"Client 1"},{color:"#009192",data:[0,0,234.65,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],label:"Client 2"},{color:"#009192",data:[0,0,490.43,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],label:"Client 3"},{color:"#009192",data:[0,0,0,94,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],label:"Client 1"}];
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {color,data,label}) => {
  if (acc[label]) acc[label].data.forEach((x, i, a) => a[i] += data[i]);
  else acc[label] = {color, data, label};
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you

```js
one = [
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 57.62, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 1"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 234.65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 2"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 490.43, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 3"
  },
  {
    color: "#009192",
    data: [0, 0, 0, 94.00, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    label: "Client 1"
  }
];

console.log(one)

let two = one.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    //console.log(acc);

    let index = (!acc.length ? null : acc.findIndex((item) => item.label === cur.label));

    if (index !== null && index >= 0) {
        acc[index].data = acc[index].data.map((value, i) => acc[index].data[i] += cur.data[i]);
    } else {
        acc.push(cur)
    }
    
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(two);
```

Regards